# Mysql not start on slave system on mysql Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.41, version (Mysql master salve replication)?

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

```
    My Configuration:
    server-id = 2
    master-host=192.1.1.12
    master-connect-retry=60
    master-user=root
    master-password=root123
    replicate-do-db=testdatabase
    relay-log = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-relay-bin
    relay-log-index = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-relay-bin.index
    log-error = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.err
    master-info-file = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-master.info
    relay-log-info-file = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-relay-log.info
    log-bin = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin
```

```
Output:

2018-09-14 08:41:10 13635 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: unknown variable 'master-host=192.1.1.12'
2018-09-14 08:41:10 13635 [ERROR] Aborting    
2018-09-14 08:41:10 13635 [Note] Binlog end
2018-09-14 08:41:10 13635 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2018-09-14 08:41:10 13635 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
```

Answer (score 2):

The master-host, -user, and -password option variables were removed from MySQL 5.5. Use the CHANGE MASTER statement instead.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-options-slave.html#replication-optvars-slaves-obsolete

Comment: I did changes but still getting the same 

server-id = 2
CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST=192.1.1.12
MASTER_USER=root
MASTER_PASSWORD=root123
MASTER_PORT=3306,
MASTER_CONNECT_RETRY=30
replicate-do-db=testdatabase
relay-log = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-relay-bin
relay-log-index = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-relay-bin.index
log-error = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.err
master-info-file = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-master.info

2018-09-14 09:08:28 14195 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: unknown variable 'CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST=192.1.1.12'
2018-09-14 09:08:28 14195 [ERROR] Aborting

Comment: CHANGE MASTER TO does not go in the config file. It is a statement that you execute on a running server.

Comment: It means no need to add anything on slave server?

Comment: Correct, nothing to change in the slave's config file, just a statement to run and the server will store that information on its own.